Cannot Build Spring Framework: ClientProtocolException when accessing spring-doc-resources
I'm trying to build the spring-framework project, v5.2.21.RELEASE, using these instructions; and when I run the following command, I get the error list below.  It appears to be attempting to access a password-protected JFrog repo to containing "spring-doc-resources".  I'm fine not building the docs if there's a workaround that will get the project built and published to Maven local.
./gradlew pTML -PskipDocs
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :downloadResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':downloadResources'.
> de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: HTTP status code: 401, URL: https://repo.spring.io/release/io/spring/docresources/spring-doc-resources/0.2.1.RELEASE/spring-doc-resources-0.2.1.RELEASE.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 39s
24 actionable tasks: 24 executed

Gradle & Java Versions
I'm trying to build with JDK 11 because the project appears to be using Gradle 5.6.4, which relies on Groovy 2.5.4, which only supports JDKs up to 11.
./gradlew --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.13 (Amazon.com Inc. 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 15.0.1 x86_64

java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)


Yes, it is on the gradle file: maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-spring-framework-build" } Did you check the readme on that repo? You need to do some tweaks.

@JorgeCampos , thank you. That points me in the right direction, but I'm not sure what tweaks need to be made to get the project to build.  Can you be more specific?

From their readme, you can try their suggestion, build from the source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source
